# How to make connection between android emulator and Gear emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy-gear

I just got the Gear SDK. I have run a few sample projects and it's working.

Now I want to make a connection between the Android Emulator and the Gear Emulator because most of the apps are developed that way, means (linked apps) we have an .apk and we also have a .wgt. Install the .APK in android emulator and .WGT in the gear emulator.

So how can I establish a connection, anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Samsung just released a guideline on how to connect a real device to a gear emulator using the SAP: http://img-developer.samsung.com/contents/cmm/Guideline_on_Testing_Gear_applications_using_the_Emulator.pdf

This worked for me, but I am also trying to connect 2 emulators (host & gear) to each other using this guideline but so far could not do it.

Comment: Please answer the question here, not by links

Comment: Did you use a samsung s4+ device ? I just tried the steps in that link using a rooted Gs2 with CM11 and the apk files just wont install. I'm not sure what devices are compatible with that tutorial.

Comment: @Vykthur D You were able to connect the s4 and gear emulator?.I am not able to even make a connection .It's always showing disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to access the Internet Connection of Mobile device from Gear 2 emulator. I have overcome this issue by passing the data/url to the Mobile device from Gear 2 in JSON format and on device side I have received this in byte[] and then converted it into Java JSONObject and extracted the data/url from it and made internet call and parsed response and sending back the response data needed in Gear 2 emulator in JSON format.